# How to handle a big .csv file in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

The raw .csv file is about 2,500,000 rows (with about 100,000 dummy rows need to be erased before we start to process it), 115 columns (id, zip, code, ..., Jan, Feb, ...Dec) .

Goal: If id & code are same, the value in each month will be added.
(But, the id & code is NOT SORTED completely.)
Then, out put the result to some smaller excel files.
(Based on the zip code.)

Q: Since it has more than 1G rows and excel can't open it, I consider to read it directly to my_array without open it in VBA.
But, if I use that way, how can I sort id & code (from my_array) quickly?
Can I delete/sort those data to my_array without open it?
Or, can anyone have better way to approach?

Thanks.

JJ

Comment: Import the CSV into a MS Access table. Create an SQL query with your criteria based on this table. Right click the recently created query and export it to csv again.

Comment: Add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime and use a textstream to read the csv sequentially line by line. Only add to your array those lines you want